# Convert date to int with Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to port some T-SQL to Hive SQL and am running into trouble with the following statement:

```
create table param as      
select convert( int, CONVERT( char(8), convert( date, begin_date ), 112 ) ) as begin_dtkey
    , convert( int, CONVERT( char(8), convert( date, end_date ), 112 ) ) as end_dtkey
    , convert( int, CONVERT( char(8), convert( date, cutoff_date ), 112 ) ) as cutoff_dtkey
    , *
from tmp_param;
```

The idea is to convert dates to their integer formats. Is there a way to do this in Hive (v0.13)?

In the case of T-SQL this was a `select`...`into` statement, but I went ahead and made it `create table`...`as select` for Hive.

Comment: do you get an error?if so, post the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way -- and one that should work in both databases -- is to use the date part extraction functions:

```
select (year(begin_date) * 10000 + month(begin_date) * 100 + day(begin_date)) as begin_dtkey,
       (year(end_date) * 10000 + month(end_date) * 100 + day(end_date)) as end_dtkey,
       (year(cutoff_date) * 10000 + month(cutoff_date) * 100 + day(cutoff_date)) as cutoff_dtkey,
       p.*
from tmp_param p;
```